# iOS autolayout incorrect in landscape mode due to portrait sized superview frame?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I’m having a problem with **Auto layout in landscape mode**. I believe it is because the frame of the parent view is expressed in portrait coordinates, e.g width=768, height=1024.

My questions are:

a) Is auto layout derived from the frame or bounds

b) If it is derived from the frame, what’s the right way to make the frame correct (usually equals bounds)?

Also, does anyone have any idea why this wasn't a problem until we rebuilt the app in Xcode 9 with iOS 11? Previously it was built with Xcode 8 and iOS 10.

Comment: *"the frame of the parent view is expressed in portrait coordinates"* -- What do you mean by that? Are you explicitly setting the `frame` of the parent view, instead of using auto-layout on that view? If so, why? If not, can you explain better what is happening? Maybe show an image or two?

Comment: Sorry - I just meant that in viewDidLoad - the width/height of the superview was 1024/768 (landscape mode). In viewDidLayoutSubviews, the width/height of the superview was changed to 768/1024 (portrait view). The layout problems appear to be from that. I'll try to add screenshots and more details.

Answer (score -2):

Fame is external view coordinate while bounds is internal.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW6

It means that position of view based on it's frame related to bounds of it's superview. Usually auto layout react on changes of orientation. Take a look on your constraints and make sure that you have no any width/height hardcoded, and you have all necessary leading/tailing and top/bottom constraints installed.

Since iOS11 apple introduced safe areas - 'virtual' space regarded to areas available for user interactions. It replaced top/bottom layout guides. You can find more details at:  https://useyourloaf.com/blog/safe-area-layout-guide/

Please provide more details for more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer to my poorly constructed question. It turns out my issue was related to code in the root view controller:     nextVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds; That evidently became a fixed sized constraint which stuck through the layout passes. Since I didn't see it immediately in the current view controller's code, I naively assumed it was being imposed on me incorrectly from iOS. Also, I was told that the layout engine was changed in iOS 11.